# Select record(s) in link wizard

Tags: typo3

The TYPO3 link wizard allows editors to select pages within the page tree.
But if an editor wants to create a link to a page loading a record (e.g. the detail page of a news record), the editor needs to insert the exact query params to pass the arguments to the page.
E.g. if the editor wants to pass the ID of a news, he / she / it needs to insert tx_news[news]=X into the field "Additional link parameters".

[image]

In my experience this often forces wrong links stored in the DB, as editors enters wrong arguments or copy the absolute link from the frontend.

Question:

Is it possible to create an own link wizard which allows editors to ...

- ... select a page AND a record from a different page

or

- ... select just a record and define the ID to the page in site config or by TypoScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi i think you are looking for thelinkhandler

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/9.5/en-us/ApiOverview/LinkBrowser/Linkhandler/Index.html

Comment: Yes, indeed exactly what I was looking for. Much easier than I expeceted.